# Shared Preference String Variable does not work in if statement

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I can not use a String Value that I get from Shared Preference in if statement.

Here's a brief description:

```
if(jm == "Mute"){
// do something
}
```

This Statement works when

```
String jm = "Mute";
```

But doesn't work when

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);

String jm = prefs.getString("key", "");
//which returns Mute
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.equals` in if statement to get work so
change

```
if(jm == "Mute"){
```

to

```
if(jm.equals("Mute")){
```

For more info see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @user3777565 Happy to help,Enjoy coding and please accept this answer so it may help others with similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Strings should be compared using equals(). Using == you are comparing references not the actual content of the string.

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)